# How to read numbers in powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement

How to read numbers in powershell can anyone please explain me this thing coded in power shell its coded like
if(($commit Id  -match 'release(-)\d+(.\d)+(.\d)$')) {echo $ci_commit}

please need a  explanation for the above code snippet i did'nt get what is coded in release(...)

Answer (score 0):

That thing is called a *regular expression*, and are a cornerstone of formal language theory in computer science. There are tons of tutorials available of different focus. For a visual representation, there are [tools too](https://regexper.com/#release%28-%29%5Cd%2B%28.%5Cd%29%2B%28.%5Cd%29%24).

That being said,

```
if(($commit Id -match 'release(-)\d+(.\d)+(.\d)$')) {echo $ci_commit}
```

means that - skipping the obvious mistake in `$commit Id` as it cannot have a space - means that it will look for text `release-`, followed by numbers, anything, numbers, dot, number and end of line.

If you need help how to create a regex, ask a new question with your attempt of regex and (wrong) results. Include some example data and what you'd like to get out of it. If there are things that should not be matched, or tricky edge cases, add those too.